# Washer and toilet water backing up into shower. Can't change plumbing. What can I do?

Tags: shower, drainage, mold, septic, laundry

Renting a tear down, landlord does next to nothing, house will be torn down. Water drainage from house is not working, also not going to be redone.
So the problem is drainage for 3 showers 4 toilets and the washing machine.
1. Downstairs issue- washer drains into shower basin. Have tried various drains to prevent this but the water comes up with force no drain cover barrier or plug prevents this, Pretty sure it is also on the septic line because is stinks more that laundry water would, also make major mold issue. 
2. All 3 toilets upstairs all have flush issues and clog often/ don't seem to have the water pressure to drain fully with a flush. 
I have been told that the main drain for the house is original, 1942,and is the root of the problems with drainage. The access to that pipe is outside under the concrete 5 step stairs. The access to pipes that flow to main drain from all bathrooms is also not accessible with out major demo and renovation of 2 bathrooms and 2 bedroom on 2 floors.

I just want to have a bit of a win with the shower backing up issue...I have been fighting mold for 2 years and I just tiled the shower basin...but I have to find a way to keep stank water from back feeding into there. 
 Other tips that may help keep this old house flowing are appreciated. 
Please don't bother telling me that the pipes need to be fixed because its not my house and the landlord doesn't care.

Comment: Clearly there is a blockage somewhere.  Find and clear it.  Yes, the main waste line is likely clogged, tree root, collapse, who knows.  The only option other than to fix it is to move somewhere else.

Comment: I pause on the note that "you are renting a tear down" - who or what deemed this to the be case? Honestly, if the house was deemed demolished, then most civilized locales also deem it illegal to live in, or rent such a building. For the health and safety concerns itself, get out. You don't own it, so you legitimately cannot repair it. There's no magic "no cost" approach to fixing this, your constriaint is not rational. @jwh20 is correct and that is an answer

Comment: "**septic line**" - when's the last time it's been pumped out?

Comment: when are you planning to leave?

Comment: @noybman perhaps SEEDS just means that the landlord has stated his intend to demolish it at some reasonably near future date, but is allowing the existing tenant to continue renting until closer to that date.  For a worthless bastard who refuses to fix any problem no matter how severe it's free money.

Comment: My point was, in most areas, the OPs post details indicate a situation where laws are being broken. Since they aren't spending money on the place besides stuffing the landlords pocket, the only option is to move. There is no free solution anticipated and their health is already in danger based clearly on the info given alone.

Answer (score 0):

I would try some sort of chemical drain cleaner/clog desolver.  This will only help with a minor plug but with repeated use may have a better effect.

Comment: Repeated use is big bucks, not to mention it can have other side effects if the system is already damaged. Since it is already backing up into multiple places "liquid" is 99.99999% if not 100% a waste of money.